# Opencv: import highgui with python

Tags: python, macos, opencv

With the following code:

```
import cv

cv.NamedWindow("w1", cv.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
camera_index = 0
capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(camera_index)

def repeat():
  global capture #declare as globals since we are assigning to them now
  global camera_index
  frame = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
  cv.ShowImage("w1", frame)
  c = highgui.cvWaitKey(10)
  if(c=="n"): #in "n" key is pressed while the popup window is in focus
    camera_index += 1 #try the next camera index
    capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(camera_index)
    if not capture: #if the next camera index didn't work, reset to 0.
        camera_index = 0
        capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(camera_index)

while True:
    repeat()
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pycam.py", line 21, in 
    repeat()
  File "pycam.py", line 12, in repeat
    c = highgui.cvWaitKey(10)
NameError: global name 'highgui' is not defined
Cleaned up camera.

Answer (score 6):

There have been quite a few changes in the new API. The following will work:

```
import cv

cv.NamedWindow("w1", cv.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
camera_index = 0
capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(camera_index)

def repeat():
  global capture #declare as globals since we are assigning to them now
  global camera_index
  frame = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
  cv.ShowImage("w1", frame)
  c = cv.WaitKey(10)
  if(c=="n"): #in "n" key is pressed while the popup window is in focus
    camera_index += 1 #try the next camera index
    capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(camera_index)
    if not capture: #if the next camera index didn't work, reset to 0.
        camera_index = 0
        capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(camera_index)

while True:
    repeat()
```

It is a simpler, cleaner syntax!

Answer (score 0):

This means that `highgui` doesn't exist. Try importing this way: `from opencv import *`.

If that doesn't work try and check your opencv instalation.